# Me marca Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function en este codigo como lo puedo arreglar?

Tags: javascript, html5, datatables, laravel-8

```
table = $('#table_id').dataTable();
//  IDS PARA EL FILTRO DE RANGO DE FECHAS

$("#min, #max").keyup(function() {
  table.draw();
});

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = $('#min').val();
    var max = $('#max').val();
    var minimo = min.toLocaleDateString("es-ES", options);
    console.log(minimo);
  }
)
```

Comment: Se te ha olvidado agregar el script de datatables seguramente o no lo estás cargando bien

Comment: Lo que dice masterguru o `table_id` no es el id real de tu tabla